# Printing Linked List

Tags: python, printing, linked-list

I have the following Linked List implementation. There is a problem with the printlist() function. The while loop is turning an error that there is no attribute next for self. Is there a better way to write this function? Thank you!!!

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data, next=None):
    self.data=data
  def _insert(self, data):
    self.next=Node(data)    
  def _find(self, data):
    if self.data==data:
      return self
    if self.next is None:
      return None
    while self.next is not None:
      if self.next.data==data:
        return self.next
    return None
  def _delete(self, data):
    if self.next.data == data:
      temp=self.next
      self.next =self.next.next
      temp=None 
  def _printtree(self):
    while self:
      print self.data,
      self=self.next
class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.head=None
  def insert(self, data):
    if self.head:
      self.head._insert(data)
    else:
      self.head=Node(data)
  def find(self, data):
    if self.head.data==data:
      return self.head
    return self.head._find(data)

  def delete(self, data):
    if self.head.data==data:
      head=None
      return
    self.head._delete(data)
  def printtree(self):
    self.head._printtree()
```

Comment: How are you calling it? Where's the full traceback? What have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `self.next=next` in your `Node.__init__` method?

Comment: Why not use __str__ instead of _printtree and printtree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add next attribute to Node's ini method
2. you should define printtree of LinkedList this way:

   def printree(self):

   ```
   current_node = self.head
   print current_node.data
   while current_node.next is not None:
       print current_node.next.data
       current_node = current_node.next
   ```

adding a **repr** method will make your code nicer